# Regex expression that matches a specific pattern but not matches another pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to put italic tags around words which are wrapped between underscores, like we do here on stack overflow format options.

I can easily do this by using this regular expression /_(.*?)_/gi. But the thing is that i don't want to put those tags in between email addresses, urls etc. So i need a regex that matches an italic pattern but not matches with url or email pattern.

```
let urlExp = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/gi;
let boldExp = /\*(.*?)\*/gi;
let italicExp = /\_(.*?)\_/gi;
let bulletedExp = /^\-\s(.*)/gm;
let emailExp = /([a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})/gi;
let modifiedText = text
    .replace(urlExp, "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>")
    .replace(emailExp, '<a href="mailto:$1">$1</a>')
    .replace(boldExp, "<strong>$1</strong>")
    .replace(italicExp, "<i>$1</i>")
    .replace(bulletedExp, "&#8226; $1");
return modifiedText;
```

Here is the code that i am working on. The issue here is that the bold, italic and bullets are also applied on urls and emails, i need to skip these two things.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: @Toto I've updated the question with the code snippet

Comment: Why not `/\s_(.*?)_\s/g`? You must put spaces around word

Comment: @Justinas then it won't change the first word in line. and won't change if a word is in between something. I only want to exclude this logic when it's between a url or email. Doesn't matter if it's between a simple word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use word boundaries (`\b`) to determine that we're at the end of a word or words with the underscores, not in the middle.

See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9jLI4B/1) for the example, using this regex:

```
\b_(.*?)_\b
```

Comment: @Toto Hi you could update it with a negative look-ahead to prevent this case, `\b_(.*?)_\b(?!@)`. See updated regex101: https://regex101.com/r/9jLI4B/6

Answer (score 0):

Just check if there are spaces or beginning or end of string:

```
let italicExp = /(^|\s)_(.*?)_(\s|$)/gi;
let modifiedText = text.replace(italicExp, "$1<i>$2</i>$3")
```

Comment: Doesn't work in all conditions. check for example this https://regex101.com/r/9jLI4B/2
it won't make it italic when there is full stop after the word, i don't care about spaces or what comes before and after. Unless it's not between a URL, or email. It should get italic.

Comment: See the italic email, here the email should be italic too :)

Comment: Guess i would need to include both yours and Jamie's logic to make it work. Means adding both space and word boundaries.
https://regex101.com/r/9jLI4B/7

Comment: Thanks for the help. Much appreciated